# How to use smack with Openfire

Tags: java, openfire, smack, google-talk, facebook-chat

Hi 
I am planning to develop a chat client which can connect to gtalk facebook etc...I have decided to use the smack API along with openfire..

But I need little guidance as to how to use it with openfire server..

And does the openfire provide a basic UI like log in box chat window etc...

I need to know how to plug or use smack with openfire

Thanks:)

Comment: Was browsing the net and came across this link that may be of use: <br/><br/>
[Instant Messaging Infrastructure](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/08/instant-messaging-infrastructure.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have decided to use the smack API along with openfire..
>   But I need little guidance as to how
>   to use it with openfire server..

What about [Smack API Getting Started](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html)?

> And does the openfire provide a basic
>   UI like log in box chat window etc...

OpenFire is just the Server. To actually chat, you'll need some Jabber/XMPP Client. You could use [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/index.jsp) for tests.

Comment: @Tim-It does not tell how I am supposed t it with openfire...Like should I plug in the smack or is there a different step

Comment: Sure, you set up the server like described here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html. Thereafter you can connect with some client or the smack API.

Comment: @Tim I have set up the openfire...I am askin how do I connect it with the smack API??

Comment: Do you have started? Post some source code along with the Exception you're getting...

Comment: @Tim...No what I meant was should I upload the jar files under plugins in openfire???

Comment: I think you haven't understood the whole thing. You need some server that understand the XMPP-Protocol. In youe case that is OpenFire, GTalk or something else. When a client connects, it sends XMPP messages as described in the protocol, see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol. So far so good, to implement a client, you could use the smack API. With this API you use Java to construct and send the XMPP messages mentioned above. So in a nutshell: The Smack API is no OpenFire Plugin and not needed on the server. You just use it to build a client.

Answer (score 4):

Configure openfire then refer to [documentation provided by Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/index.html). It has easy to understand examples. FYI openfire works fine with gtalk but with facebook it is very slow.

---

Sample code:-

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, 5222);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login(user_name, password);
```

Here host is the ip/domain name where openfire is configured.

Comment: @Harry-I have gone through the documentation but I dint see anywhere as to how to use smack with openfire...I have the openfire configured...

Comment: @Kuber: to just simply use opefire with smack. No extra jar file is needed. But to work with gtalk/facebook you will requires plugins in openfire.

Comment: So where so I code for it??In eclipse..should I configure openfire in eclipse??

Comment: @Kuber: no need to configure openfire in eclipse. Download SMACK jars. Then just create a java file copy/paste above code. replace username/host/password. Run the file.

Comment: So how does the openfire understand ??I mean I don see any set up or configuration..So how does the openfire know??

Comment: @kuber: We are providing ip and port on which openfire is running.

Comment: hi any tell me wat is the host here

Comment: @Kannappan: host is the ip or domain name of the machine where openfire is running.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample, which will help set the status message on gtalk.

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

public class SmackToGtalk {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
            "talk.google.com", 5222, "google.com");
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    Presence presence;
    String status;

    try {
        connection.connect();
        connection.login("mail_id@gmail.com", "password");
        status = "DND";

        presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available, status, 24,
                Presence.Mode.available);
        while (true) {
            status = set(status);
            presence.setStatus(status);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}

private static String set(String input) {
    return input.substring(1) + input.charAt(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSP / Java, import the smack.jar

```
<%@ page import="org.jivesoftware.smack.*;" %>
```

Place smack.jar in

```
tomcat/lib
```

or 
    yourwebapp/WEB-INF/lib